# Operator overloading in queue

Tags: c++, queue, operator-overloading

so what im trying to dois overload the - operator in a queu in order to remove the numbers in common with another queue from a queue.
ex:
queue A:[5 4 3 7]
queue B:[5 2 1 7]

A-B

A=[4 3]

i have done this:

```
CFilaInteiros& operator-(const CFilaInteiros& b)
    {
    if ( inicio == NULL )
    cout << "Fila vazia..." << endl;
    else
    {
        CNoFila * aux = inicio;
        while( aux != NULL )
        {
            if(aux->dados==b->dados) retiraDaFila(aux->dados);
            aux = aux->proximo;
        }
    }
}
```

Im writing this beacause this says i have to mutch code 
here is the header:

```
#ifndef CFilaInteiros_h
#define CFilaInteiros_h

using namespace std;

class CFilaInteiros;

class CNoFila{
    int dados;
    CNoFila *proximo;

    friend class CFilaInteiros; // permite a esta classe aceder atributos private
};

class CFilaInteiros
{
private:
    CNoFila *inicio, *fim;
public:
    CFilaInteiros(void);
    ~CFilaInteiros(void);

    void insereNaFila(const int item);
    bool retiraDaFila(int &item);
    void escreveFila(void) const;
    bool filaVazia(void) const { return (inicio == NULL ); }
    CFilaInteiros& operator-(const CFilaInteiros& b)
    {

        if ( inicio == NULL )
        cout << "Fila vazia..." << endl;
        else
        {
            CNoFila * aux = inicio;
            while( aux != NULL )
            {
                if(aux->dados==b->dados) retiraDaFila(aux->dados);
                aux = aux->proximo;
            }
        }
    }

};

#endif
```

retiradafila(takes node from queue):

```
bool CFilaInteiros::retiraDaFila(int &item){
 if (inicio == NULL) return false; 


 item = inicio->dados;


 CNoFila * aux = inicio;
 inicio = aux->proximo;

 if (inicio == NULL) fim = NULL;
 delete aux;   
 return true;  
}
```

Comment: That's a strange operation for a queue. Do you know how to write an operator, in general?

Comment: a bit, i know i have to do something like this: CFilaInteiros& operator-(const CFilaInteiros&)

Comment: @José Silva This operator does not make sense for queues.

Comment: its on the exercise, it also says to be aware of the standard operator declaration. Sorry if its poorly translated, the exercise is in portuguese

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer `-=`? And what if A is `[5 7 3 4]` and B is `[5 2 7 1]`?

Comment: the exercise explicitly says thats only - operator(CFilaInteiros::operator-)
and that A-B would be [3 4]

Comment: Yes! A-B would be [3 4], but A would still be [5 4 3 7]. That's the difference between `-` and `-=`. Are you writing your own queue, or using `std::queue`?

Comment: i'm writing it.

Comment: That makes things easier. In your code it appears that you iterate over A; shouldn't you iterate over B instead?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not following, could you elaborate?

Comment: If you post the declaration of `CFilaInteiros`, I will try to show what I mean.

Comment: @Beta here you go i posted the header, i would be really nice if you could help me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted:

```
CFilaInteiros& operator-(const CFilaInteiros& b)
{
    ...
    CNoFila * aux = inicio;
    while( aux != NULL )
    {
        if(aux->dados==b->dados) retiraDaFila(aux->dados);
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }
}
```

But `b->dados` is incorrect (`b` is not a pointer, and `CFilaInteiros` has no `dados`), and you are iterating over A but not over B, which cannot work.

I suggest you iterate over B:

```
CNoFila * aux = b.inicio;
while( aux != NULL )
  {
    retiraDaFila(aux->dados);
    aux = aux->proximo;
  }
```

Comment: this removed the nodes from A and copied them to B, now A is empty

Comment: @JoséSilva: I do not understand how this code can add elements to B, nor how it can remove elements from A other than the ones passed as arguments to  `retiraDaFila`. Can you verify that the code iterates over B? Can you post the definition of `retiraDaFila`?

Comment: posted retiradafila. I managed to make it work but only when the equal nodes are on the same index.                                                                                          
            CNoFila * aux = inicio;
            CNoFila * aux2 = b.inicio;
            while( aux != NULL )
            {
                if(aux->dados==aux2->dados) retiraDaFila(aux->dados);
                aux = aux->proximo;
                aux2=aux2->proximo;
            }

Comment: now if A=[1 2 3 4] and B=[1 2 3 5]    A-B   A=[4]   but if A=[1 2 3 4] and B=[4 3 2 1], A stays the same and it should've become empty

Comment: @JoséSilva: I assumed that `retiraDaFila` deleted the value given as an argument. But your `retiraDaFila` does not use its argument at all, it simply deletes the first element. You must write a function that takes an `int` argument, and deletes all nodes with that value. (Whether you call it `retiraDaFila` or something else, it is the function that `operator-` will call.)

Comment: you're the best, it now works as intended, at least if i understood the exercise correctly hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy :D

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Queue {
public:
    vector<int> container;

    Queue(vector<int> items) : container(items) {
    }

    void operator-(const Queue& other) {
        vector<int> resultContainer;
        for (size_t i=0; i<container.size(); ++i) {
            if (container[i] != other.container[i]) {
                resultContainer.push_back(container[i]);
            }
        }
        container.clear();
        for (int item : resultContainer) {
            container.push_back(item);
        }
    }

    void printValues() {
        for (int item : container) {
            cout<<item<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Queue A(vector<int>{5,4,3,7});
    Queue B(vector<int>{5,2,1,7});

    cout<<"before:\nA = ";
    A.printValues();
    cout<<"B = ";
    B.printValues();
    cout<<endl;

    A - B;

    cout<<"after:\nA = ";
    A.printValues();
    cout<<"B = ";
    B.printValues();
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"end"<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
before:
A = 5 4 3 7 
B = 5 2 1 7 

after:
A = 4 3 
B = 5 2 1 7 

end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that vector library and i have already some methods that i have to use                                                                                                                               void insereNaFila(const int item);//add to the queue
bool retiraDaFila(int &item);//remove from queue
void escreveFila(void) const;//write the queue
bool filaVazia(void) const { return (inicio == NULL ); } //check if queue is empty                                   but thanks for the help:)